# Angularjs ng-checked not working

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

I am generating checkboxes trough ng-repeat , for all columns of some grid

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in gridData[0]">
                                   <!--<label>{{columnShowSelect[1].columnNumber}}</label>-->
                                   <div class="section col-md-6">
                                       <label>
                                           <u>
                                               <h5>{{key}}</h5>
                                           </u>
                                       </label>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="section col-md-4">
                                       <u>
                                           <label class="block mt15 option option-primary">
                                               <input type="checkbox" id="chbEnableCol" name="chbColumnName" value="{{$index+1}}"  ng-checked="columnShowSelect[{{$index}}].columnNumber == {{$index+1}}" />
                                               <span class="checkbox"></span>Enable this column</label></u>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
```

I also want to check checkboxes which i have already decided to be checked , so i am getting  json with columnNumbers , that is columnShowSelect.columnNumber ,but for some reason it doesnt check it , if i put {{columnShowSelect[$index].columnNumber}} and go inspect element of checkbox , i can clearly see that it says ng-checked= "1 == 1" , but checkbox is not checked , any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `{{}}` in [`ng-checked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) because it takes **JavaScript expression**.

```
ng-checked="columnShowSelect[$index].columnNumber == $index+1"
```

Comment: I spent 5 hours figuring out what am i doing wrong , to have that simple mistake , thank you sir :)

Comment: You're welcome! Angular directives are sometimes confusing because some of them take expressions and the others take just strings...